# How to format a large string with a pattern that changes sometimes into a CSV format in java

Tags: java, string, csv, formatting

I have a very large string that was a result of parsing and want to format it into csv format, that data is class information, currently is is just listed out as seen below, It has a pattern to it, but in a few cases is irregular. For example below I have the three cases , the first three lines is what the majority of the data looks like (class name, time, day), but is some cases the as seen by the middle case an extra time and day line are added(class name, time, day, time, day), and as seen by the last case, some classes dont have a time and day. (the actually data doesn't have a blank line in between it, I put it there to show the different cases)

```
CHM 110 - 10
9:30 am - 10:45 am
Thursday    

CSC 150 - 04
10:30 am - 11:45 am
Monday
11:30 am - 12:45 am
Wednesday 

BIO 132 - 01
```

How would I turn this data into a csv file, for example the above input would be format as such.

```
CHM 110 - 10, 9:30 am - 10:45 am, Thursday  

CSC 150 - 04,10:30 am - 11:45 am, Monday, 11:30 am - 12:45 am, Wednesday 

BIO 132 - 01
```

Not sure if im overthinking it, but i was thinking since every class has a name that is three capital letters followed by three numbers a dash and two numbers, could it be split from there somehow, put it into a single line and add commas to it.

Comment: Why wouldnt you use blank lines as delimiters for your records in this case?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi the actually data doesn't have a blank line inbetween it, I just put it there to split the different cases, but good idea if it did have blank lines.

Comment: Then use the first 3 letters in caps as markers for start of record

Answer (score 0):

Each line can be extracted using regular expressions patterns which looks for Zero or One occurrence of given pattern.

Pattern can start with 3 chars alphabet, number , time and ending with Day of week. This could solve in extracting data in required format.